# Unable to retrieve secret from Google Secret Manager from Rails 6 application

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, ruby-on-rails-6, google-secret-manager

Following the [Secret Manager docs](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets), I created a secret which I now try to programmatically retrieve. My implementation looks like this:

```
require 'google/cloud/secret_manager'

class SecretManager
  def self.read(secret_id)
    return unless secret_id
    Google::Cloud::SecretManager.secret_manager_service.access_secret_version(
      name: "projects/my-test-project/secrets/#{secret_id}/versions/latest"
    ).payload.data
  end
end
```

On execution I get the following:

```
irb(main):001:0> SecretManager.read('my-test-key')
objc[9757]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[9757]: +[__NSCFConstantString initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
```

Also, I found this issue (which is around 2 years old): https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14009 but the proposed solution doesn't work out for me.

I'm running OSX 10.14.6, Ruby 2.6.5, Rails 6.0.2.1

Comment: Break it down: does `Google::Cloud::SecretManager` work? Does `Google::Cloud::SecretManager.secret_manager_service` work? Does `Google::Cloud::SecretManager.secret_manager_service.access_secret_version(...)` work? Does `Google::Cloud::SecretManager.secret_manager_service.access_secret_version(...).payload` work?

Comment: Are you on OS X Mojave by chance? If so, try `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES`